# Using SSJS to retrieve bounce data

Tags: javascript, marketing-cloud, ssjs

I'd like to create an SSJS script which retrieves bounced emails from a send activity. I've tried testing by creating a simple landing page and started by retrieving **sent** emails for now, but it just returns a list of commas:

```
 <p>,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,</p>
```

Here's the landing page html that I am using:

```
 <script runat="server">    
    Platform.Load('Core','1'); 
</script>

<html>

<body style="font-size: 12px;color: #000099; font-family: verdana;">

<script runat="server">
var singleSend = Send.Init(573180);
var results = singleSend.Tracking.TotalByInterval.Retrieve('Send', '01-01-2014', '07-31-2014', 'day');
Write('<p>' + results + ' </p>');

</script>

<script>Write('<p>' + results + ' </p>');</script>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm assuming that '506903' is the tracking "Job ID" that's displayed in the tracking interface. Can anyone explain why this does not work?

Comment: Did you mean 506903 instead of 573180 in your code?

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant 573180

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In place of:

```
Write('<p>' + results + ' </p>');
```

Try:

```
Write('<p>' + Stringify(results) + ' </p>');
```

That will help display the structure of the object.

The results variable is an array of hashes which is why just using Write() doesn't output it correctly.

Example Code for looping through the array and pulling out the fields from the hash:

```
var arrayLength = results.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    Write('<p> Start: ' + results[i]['RangeStart'] + ', End: ' + results[i]['RangeEnd'] + ', Total: ' + results[i]['Total'] + ', Unique: ' + results[i]['Unique'] + '</p>');
}
```

Edit: Also the 2nd line where it is using Write() needs to have the script tag include the server-side attribute. 
Currently:

```
<script>Write('<p>' + results + ' </p>');</script>
```

Change to:

```
<script runat="server">Write('<p>' + results + ' </p>');</script>
```